# How to replicate Tera Term SerialPort command in C#?

Tags: c#, serial-port, teraterm

In Tera Term I'm connecting to a serial device over USB (on startup select radiobutton "serial" and correct port). Once connected I only change the default speed to 115200 (in setup=> serial port).

After this, tera term asks me to fill in commands like so:

Command>

I fill in the device specific command. In this case it's "PC" and I receive an expected response ie. "ABC"

---

Now I'm trying to do the same in C#. Unfortunately the response I get is always the same as the command I actually type in.

So If I type in "PC", the response is "PC", but I expect "ABC". Other commands have the same problem. Command "?" responds with "?" while I expect "CBA".

If I type in a faulty command => then I get the message "Unknown command"
So I suspect the device actually gets the right command.

I'm using the following code:

```
        SerialPort COMport = new SerialPort(Port_Name, Baud_Rate); //Create a new  SerialPort Object (defaullt setting -> 8N1)
        COMport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sPort_dataReceived);
        COMport.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(sPort_ErrorReceived);


        COMport.BaudRate = 115200;
        COMport.Parity = Parity.None;
        COMport.DataBits = 8;
        COMport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        COMport.RtsEnable = true;
        COMport.Handshake = Handshake.None;


        COMport.Open();


        COMport.WriteLine(Data);

        Thread.Sleep(1000); // Just discovered after a lot of testing that this is necessary to read the response before the Comport closes

        COMport.Close();
```

Then I do the following:

```
    private void sPort_dataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.Write(indata);

        MessageBox.Show(indata);

    }
```

I've tried different things, but I can't get this to work. Hopefully it's because I'm new to this. I've never worked with Tera term before.

Thanks in advance,

**Some (but definately not all) things I've tried:**

tried this guys advise and code: https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

downloaded and tried from here: https://www.xanthium.in/building-opensource-gui-based-serial-port-communication-program-dot-net-framework-and-arduino#simple-serial-source-code (Although my device is not arduino)

Tried to add "\r\n" : [C# Errors with SerialPort WriteLine commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928474/c-sharp-errors-with-serialport-writeline-commands)

---

EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT

So I found out more. If I use the following code (Write instead of WriteLine), I do get good results but not every time:

Sending the full command now: "Command>PC"

```
        string Command1 = txtCommand.Text;
        Command1 = Command1 + "\r\n";
        string CommandSent;
        int Length, j = 0;

        Length = Command1.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            CommandSent = Command1.Substring(j, 1);
            ComPort.Write(CommandSent);
            j++;
        }
```

The first time, now I get good results. The second time I get "Unknow Command", the 3rd time => good results, 4th = "Unknown Command"... etc...
It always seems to work 1 time well, then 1 time not.

I can only get it to work consistently if I switch the command formatting:

First time command: "Command>PC"

Second time command: "PC"

Third time command : "Command>PC"

Fourth time command: "PC"

etc...

I've already tried to clear the buffer before sending but no effect.

```
        ComPort.DiscardInBuffer();
        ComPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
```

Comment: The sleep is not necessary.  The issue is the application need to block so it doesn't close.  You can simply put a Console.ReadLine() to block so you can receive .message.  Also remove the Close() so you can receive message.

Comment: @jdweng thanks, the 1 second interval seems to be enough to receive the message. I've also tested without the close. Any ideas on the actual problem? thanks again

Comment: You do not get the entire receive message in one ReadExisting() method.  You have to read until the entire message is received.  You are sending using COMport.WriteLine() so you have to wait until the end of line occurs before processing the receive data which may take more than one dataReceived Event.   So when you receive data you put it in a buffer.  Then test if the return is in the message.  Only process message after you receive the return.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your comments, it has given me insight on the fact that I'm not doing something extraordinarily wrong. (I have followed your advice and tested the readExisting further to make sure there is no message left). Can you please look at my EDIT?... perhaps things are more clear now...

Comment: You have to marge incoming data to get complete message if you get "Command>"  (no return) then "PC\n".  You input buffer has to be "Command>PC\n".  Some communication devices that send continuously you may have to flush the buffer when you start "abc\nCommand>PC\n".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Newline seemed to be a problem.

I needed to use Comport.Write (instead of WriteLine). Then Also I needed to append a carriage return "\r" but NO newline '\n' as I previously thought. (the incoming data showed a newline after the "Command>" making it impossible to send another meaningfull command => the cause of this was '\n' => removing it solved the problem)

This is my current code that seems to work (I no longer need to append "Command>", just sending the command as is):

```
        if (thecommand == "")
        {
            ComPort.Write("\r"); //start from a clean slate
            return;
        }

        ComPort.DiscardInBuffer();
        ComPort.DiscardOutBuffer();

        string Command1 = thecommand + "\r";

        ComPort.Write(Command1);
```